# Integrating PHP into Javascript (unexpected token)

Tags: javascript, php

Why would javascript return an 'unexpected token <' error when integrating php inline with javascript?

Example:

```
var labelPts = <?php echo json_encode($label) ?>;
```

This example is within a .js script called from a *.php webpage

Comment: Because the PHP would have to be processed on the server. Browsers don't know anything about PHP.

Comment: Unless your server is configured to run .js files through the php interpreter, then the php code will be interpreted client side, as (incorrect) javascript

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez in a single executing echo line you don't need a semi-colon (granted it's preferred for readability but it's not required) but since it's echoing JSON he should have quotes.

Comment: php is only executed in files that contain a php extension (i.e. `.php`, `.phtml`, `.php5`, etc.) since your php is not in a php file, the webserver won't execute this code. A better thing to do would be to create an AJAX request to pull that data in asynchronously from the server where php CAN be executed

Comment: It is also possible that the JSON data comes with special characters.

Comment: It is also possible that JavaScript is not the problem. Maybe the problem is when getting the JSON data and JavaScript is just showing the PHP error.

Comment: The answer posted solved the unexpected token error, but unfortunately for me it fills the array with the characters used in the php code. I marked it as the answer since it solves the problem I specified, I suspect the problem is with it being a client-side request (like Steve said above). Thus, I will likely be trying an AJAX request like @iamde_coder suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can read here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php , JSON data comes with double quotes. So JavaScript will need single quotes to display the string with JSON data. Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>By José Manuel Abarca Rodríguez</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
?>

var txt = '<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>'; // NOTICE THE SINGLE QUOTES!!!

function show_json () {
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = txt;
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <button onclick="show_json();">Get JSON data from server</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="my_div">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Copy-paste previous code into a textfile, save it with PHP extension and run it in your brower with localhost/filename.php. It works fine.